# OpenCv c++ cvPutText always throws "Unknown array type" when used with Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

This is the simplified code:

```
try {
    Mat pic = imread("../files/words.bmp");
    CvFont font;
    cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, 1.0);
    cvPutText(&pic, "text", cvPoint(1, 20), &font, cvScalar(0, 255, 0));
    namedWindow("x", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("x", pic);
    return 0;
} catch(Exception& e) {
    cout << e.err;
}
```

As in the topic, the effect is that cvPutText always throws an exception with message "Unknown array type".
I know I can use PutText instead - it works perfectly, but I want to set the width and height of the font independently and only the old cvPutText has feature like that. 
Does anyone know what format the Mat needs to be to work with cvPutText? Or I need to do some other conversions?

Comment: Make sure `Mat pic` loads the image successfully. Try to put `imshow("x", pic);` before `cvPutText()`.

Comment: The pic is loaded successfully, I checked this. Debug shows its type is UINT8.

Comment: use cv::putText instead.

Comment: As I said. I don't want to use cv::putText, because it doesn't give me possibility to stretch the text. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are mixing up C and C++ style APIs of OpenCV. C style `cvPutText()` can only handle images of type `IplImage *`, not for C++ style `Mat`.

You need to change it to

```
IplImage *pic = cvLoadImage("../files/words.bmp");
CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, 1.0);
cvPutText(pic, "text", cvPoint(1, 20), &font, cvScalar(0, 255, 0));
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the C++ style API, i.e. [`putText()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext).

---

**P.S.:** Suggestion: try not to mix up C and C++ APIs.